# how to find default browser in registry windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser, windows-registry, regedit

i need to find my default browser so first i try to figure it through regedit (registy keys)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968449/how-do-i-change-default-browser-using-c-sharp-or-batch-file as mentioned i used reg key{HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command} then i manual change my web browser from internet explore to chrome. but after i refresh values does not change in reg key. why this happen??? how can i detect my default browser in reg key?

**EDIT :**

always

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command
```

value is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome
```

(even i change to chrome to default browser this does not change)

Comment: It sounds you're like you're trying to programmatically change registry values, so maybe this belong on StackOverflow with notes on what language/tools you're using.

Comment: @ckhan-yah i try to do it.. but before that i check it in reg edit. if i change browsers manually (explorer to chrome) then according to that does regkey change it values or not???? but in here it does not change in windows 7. i want to know why this happen & how can i see the changes.

Comment: See http://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/

Comment: @ckhan i read that one. but it does not mention about windows 7. :(

Comment: Which Programming language are you using with what function?

Comment: @Akshat Mittal im not using any language now. i just change default browser manually. always HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command value is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome (even i change to chrome

Comment: You want to Get the Default browser or Change it.

Comment: @Akshat Mittal i want to find my default browser in reg key values

Answer (score 11):

You can look under this registry key and find out which browser is being used by the current user:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\Progid
```

It is a `REG_SZ` value and will be one of these for the major three browsers currently available:

- FirefoxURL
- ChromeHTML
- IE.HTTP

Comment: great... this is nice.

Comment: Chrome beta/dev/canary: `ChromeBHTML`/`ChromeDHTML`/`ChromeSSHTM`. Edgium stable/beta/dev/canary: `MSEdgeHTM`/`MSEdgeBHTML`/`MSEdgeDHTML`/???.