# Change the default browser automatically on startup (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch, internet-explorer, default-settings

I've just gotten a new laptop from university and everytime I change my default browser to Chrome (by default it is internet explorer) it resets to IE when I restart my computer. So I went to the laptop service center on our university. And they were able to tell me that it is happening everytime I connect to a network by default. It's some stupid new policy, and they're not agreeing with it as well.

So it got me thinking about how to make a workaround and I think the best way is to have a program (i.e batch script change the registry or something else) on startup. I've been looking around google and searching different things for quite some time now but I'm not really sure how to do it..

Can someone help me out or send me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to be an Administrator on the PC to do this.  The fact this is happening means, there is a group policy, or the pc is rolling back to a specific image.

Comment: Check ["HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice"](http://superuser.com/a/571854/376602). No need to  be an Administrator on the PC to change this. However, I can't know if some group policy rule would overwrite it or vice versa.

Comment: I am an administrator on the pc, it's just setting it back everytime I reboot and am connected to a network. The UserChoice is currently set to Chrome. It think it is just overwritten on startup for some reason ;/. Thats why I would like to have some sort of batch script change it at startup since it's fine then.

Comment: Did you have any program like deep freeze installed on your PC ?

Comment: Yes quite a lot of programs but not deep freeze.. It doesn't like restore my system though like deep freeze seems to do. It just changes certain settings back to the ones they want me to use.

Comment: Please clarify, does the default browser change on startup, even if you're not connected to the network, or do you have to be connected to the network for it to reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a little program that can do this: [Set Default Browser](https://github.com/sampalmer/set-default-browser). You could run it on startup. No guarantee it will work for your situation, though.